# Lining an in-ground container

Tags: wood, moisture

I plan to dig a hole and put things in said hole. My problem is, some of the things that will be buried can't or shouldn't be directly exposed to the ground, either for their benefit or the Earth's. Also, because this hole is expected to be ~2x2x4', I can't simply buy an enclosure (like if it were cable in PVC).

Can I reasonably build a box with pressure-treated plywood to line the hole, or will I need moisture barriers, sealant, etc.?

Comment: I have used 55 gallon drums in the past to make a large inground box. They are close to the size you want but holes will need to be drilled in the bottom so any moisture that gets in can drain. The metal ones last for decades the plastic ones will probably last forever.

Comment: That's actually a great idea. The only problem is that the box simply contains an insulated cement pour. It's acting as a large thermal capacitor. I'd rather not have the insulation contact the ground directly, but need *some* insulation because moist soil is surprisingly good at transferring heat.